# Java HashSet preserving first and last element

Tags: java, hashset

I'm trying to remove duplication from a list of list of characters using java.

**Example:**

[a, c, b] ---> List of characters 1

[a, c, e, b] ---> List of characters 2

[a, c, **a**, **c**, e, b] ---> List of characters 3

For the first and the second list because we do not have a duplication so need to modify them, **but** for the **3rd list** we do have a duplication so i need to remove the duplication without touching the first and the last element of the list so the final result will be
**[a, c, e, b]**.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;


public class Execution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        execution();

    }

    private static <V> void execution() {
        Graph<Character> graph = new Graph<>(
                new Edge<>('a', 'c', 1.0),
                new Edge<>('c', 'a', 1.0),

                new Edge<>('b', 'c', 2.0),
                new Edge<>('c', 'b', 2.0),

                new Edge<>('c', 'e', 1.0),
                new Edge<>('e', 'c', 1.0),

                new Edge<>('b', 'e', 1.0),
                new Edge<>('e', 'b', 1.0),

                new Edge<>('e', 'd', 3.0),
                new Edge<>('d', 'e', 3.0),

                new Edge<>('d', 'b', 2.0),
                new Edge<>('b', 'd', 2.0)

        );

        List<Path<Character>> paths = new DefaultKShortestPathFinder<Character>().findShortestPaths('a', 'b', graph, 3);
        List<List<Character>> nodes = new ArrayList<List<Character>>();
        List<HashSet<Character>> modified = new ArrayList<HashSet<Character>>();

        for(Path<Character> path:paths) {
            nodes.add(path.getNodeList());

        }


        for(List<Character> p:nodes) {
          modified.add(new HashSet<>(p));

        }

        for(HashSet<Character> n:modified) {
          System.out.println(n);

        }


    }

}
```

**Output of my code:**

```
[a, b, c] [a, b, c, e] [a, b, c, e]
```

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the duplication but when i use the HashSet it removes my first and last element and as i said the first and the element can't be removed from the list. 
Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to remove the duplication but when i use the HashSet it removes my first and last element

`HashSet` doesn't remove the first or last element. `HashSet` prevents duplicates and has no ordering, so there is no meaning to the first or last element in a `HashSet`.

If I understood the question, you want to remove duplicates while preserving the order of the elements of the original `List`s. Use `LinkedHashSet` (which preserves insertion order):

```
modified.add(new LinkedHashSet<>(p));
```

Actually, that would only take care of keeping the first element in the first position, so if the last element of the original `List` has multiple occurrences, it won't stay in the last position (since the last position of the `List` would contain a character already added to the `Set`). You'll have to remove and re-add it to the `Set` after creating the `modified.add(new LinkedHashSet<>(p))` call.

```
for(List<Character> p:nodes) {
    LinkedHashSet<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(p);
    set.remove(p.get(p.size()-1));
    set.add(p.get(p.size()-1));
    modified.add(set);
}
```

Comment: Yes i did use LinkedHashSet but if i use k=100(Number of iteration) it won't preserve the order here is the execution: 

[a, c, b]
[a, c, e, b]
[a, c, b, e]
[a, c, b]
so for the third list i did remove the last element and for my case the first and last element must not be removed.

Comment: i did understand what you've said but for the two last lines i didn't get it.
set.remove(p.get(p.size()-1));
set.add(p.get(p.size()-1));
Thanks for your help